# How to execute python script from bitbake bb file during yocto build

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake

**Question**:
Symilary as in subject - I want to execute python script during yocto build.

**Problem description**:
I have ready python script witch I want to execute during processing bb file of some meta-layer. I have no idea how to do this properly. Does anybody can support me in this case?

Comment: I wonder, what this script is used for? Does it generate some file that needs to be installed or evaluate some build option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the "do_{something}" steps run bash commands, which should be able to run python scripts.

You probably want to run it in do_install.

Alternatively you can run these steps in python instead of bash by writing python before the name of the steps. For example:

```
python do_install{
```

I didn't test any of this personally, but I saw this done in different recipe files(the opencv recipe for example)